# citation undefined problem (reference list disappear)

Tags: bibliographies

[image]

I opened this template and added the other reference bibtex file.
**Overleaf to Texmaker Bibtex Template**

After delete the added file, the reference list disappeared.

main file and bibliography file text is exactly same with the original template.

Anyone who knows solution, please leave comment.

---

#### `main.tex`

```
% BEGIN -- SETUP DOCUMENT (OVERLEAF) --
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\let\cite\parencite
\begin{document}
% END -- SETUP DOCUMENT (OVERLEAF) --

% BEGIN -- SETUP DOCUMENT (TEXMAKER) --
% \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{apacite}
% \begin{document}
% \bibliographystyle{apacite}
% END -- SETUP DOCUMENT (TEXMAKER) --

\title{ Overleaf to Texmaker Bibtex Template }
\author{Zhen Yong Lee}
\date{May 12, 2016}
\maketitle

\section{Literature Review}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Bit Weaving} \cite{meiners_liu_torng_2012}: if match fields of two entries differ by only one bit and their action fields are same, these two entries can be merged. 
\item \textbf{Dependent-set caching}  : Each rule is assigned a ``cost'' corresponding to the number of rules that must be installed together and a ``weight'' corresponding to the number of packets expected to hit that rule. The current problem of maximizing the total weight can be formulated as a linear integer programming problem, where each rule has a variable indicating whether the rule is installed in the cache.

\end{enumerate}

\section{Research Methodology}

To verify our results, we will simulate real data center traffic by using ClassBench . ClassBench will be used to generate synthetic rule policy with a different type of packet classification; this will be implemented using C language. 
\\\\
ClassBench is a good choice for simulating a near real data center environment. It generates synthetic rule policy with the desired rule number and dependency using a database from a real data center. In this simulation, we intend to take the standard policy Access Control List, IP Chain and Firewall from the seed files provided by ClassBench.

% BEGIN -- END DOCUMENT (OVERLEAF) --
\printbibliography
\end{document}
% END -- END DOCUMENT (OVERLEAF) --

% BEGIN -- END DOCUMENT (TEXMAKER) --
% \bibliography{ref}{}
% \end{document}
% END -- END DOCUMENT (TEXMAKER) --
```

#### `ref.bib`

```
@article{taylor_turner_2007, 
    title={ClassBench: A Packet Classification Benchmark}, 
    volume={15}, 
    DOI={10.1109/tnet.2007.893156}, 
    number={3}, 
    journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking IEEE/ACM Trans. Networking}, 
    author={Taylor, David E. and Turner, Jonathan S.}, 
    year={2007}, 
    pages={499–511}
} 

 @misc{katta_2014,
    title = {Rule-Caching Algorithms for Software-Defined Networks},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jrex/papers/cacheflow-long14.pdf}},
    author={Naga Katta, Omid Alipourfard, Jennifer Rexford and David Walker},
    year = {2014}
}

 @article{meiners_liu_torng_2012, 
    title={Bit Weaving: A Non-Prefix Approach to Compressing Packet Classifiers in TCAMs}, 
    volume={20}, 
    DOI={10.1109/tnet.2011.2165323}, 
    number={2}, 
    journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking IEEE/ACM Trans. Networking}, 
    author={Meiners, C. R. and Liu, A. X. and Torng, E.}, 
    year={2012}, 
    pages={488–500}
}
```

Comment: For starters, you must uncomment the lines from `\documentclass` to `\bibliographystyle`. (According to the screenshot you posted, those lines of code are commented out...) After those lines of code become active, you'll have to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more in order to (a) create the formatted bibliography and (b) make resolve all citation call-outs.

Comment: What Mico said is absolutely true for the screenshot. For the information you just posted, you do *not* need `\bibliographystyle` (it actually is forbidden) and you have to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations